# Where can I find live order book data for crypto with paper trading feature on the cloud for $50-$100 a month?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, limit-order-book

We're a startup creating an algorithmic trading bot for cryptocurrencies and looking for a website where we can fetch **live**, not historical limit order book (LOB) data for up to 100$ a month.

I'd like to paper trade our strategy and need continuous live LOB data to do so.

I've checked multiple website like Binance, Crypto Lake, Tradingview and Quantconnect. The latter offers a subscription that requires too many add-ons, the sum ends up at 300$!

If anyone has recommendations, I'd be happy to check them out!

Thanks in advance :)